Is it possible to have dialogs without address bar when developing for Outlook web?
I am planning to create an extension for Outlook web. I want to show a dialog for e.g. selecting a folder. Having scrolled through the tutorials I've only seen dialogs including an address bar or using a sidebar to show my content. Is it possible to show dialogs without an address bar? How would that look like?

The short answer is yes which is applicable for Outlook for Web only, as the other platforms will not display the address bar.
And the long answer is as follows...
When using displayDialogAsync method of Office.UI interface, there is an optional parameter options which can be set to change the appearance of the dialog. The Office.DialogOptions interface displayInIframe property determines whether the dialog box should be displayed within an IFrame. This setting is only applicable in Office for Web, and is ignored by other platforms. If false (default), the dialog will be displayed as a new browser window (pop-up). Recommended for authentication pages that cannot be displayed in an IFrame. If true, the dialog will be displayed as a floating overlay with an IFrame. This is best for user experience and performance.
For example, the dialog displayed by Outlook for Web in IFrame ...


thanks for your reply, but wouldn't the short answer then be "yes", because your dialog is not a browser popup with an address bar but a "real dialog"? I has a forced title if I understand you right, but not a forced address bar? :-)

I have corrected the answer, hope this is what you asked.

perfect, thank you! accepted as answer :-)
